# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) in java

Tags: java, javascript, regex, escaping

I am using URL Matching with parent domain and I-Frame domain. Getting this error to put the below code inside Java Class.

```
out.print("ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];");
```

Getting Error for this line:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

Original script:

```
    out.print("<script>");
```

//need to put below line inside java class, so using `out.print(" ");`

```
ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
out.print("</script>");
```

How to use this correctly?

Comment: java is not same as javascript!!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor: It's more of a Java question, in the end. It's Java outputting JavaScript code, and the Java string needs escaping.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : OP tagged `javascript` in this question, while regex here was purely on Java...so i dropped a comment!! :)

Comment: that was a javascript code added in java class..thats why added a tag for javascript..@NoobEditor

Comment: @NoobEditor: The *regex* was purely JavaScript. It was being output by a Java method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a Java string, to actually have a backslash you have to escape it with another backslash. So all `\` should be escaped with another `\` in your `out.print` line:

```
out.print("ref = url.match(/:\\/\\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];");
                      //     ^  ^
```

That outputs this:

```
ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\\` instead of `\` when you are escaping characters.